# reading out many graphs causes resulting plots to be tiny and squeezed together

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, export, data-visualization

I produced some code to create a boxplot for each value in the "Replica" column of my dataframe. This works if there are only say,  [4 unique values in the column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJSu1.png). However, when there are many values the plot produced looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PHXU.png), everything is so shrunken and tightly packed that it becomes impossible to see anything.

the code to produce the graphs is:

```
`ggplot(dataframe, aes(x=Replica, y=value, fill=concentration)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.1)+
  geom_boxplot(fill="red") +
  scale_y_log10() +
  labs(title="", x="", y="Distance moved in 60s (log10 scale)")+
  facet_wrap(~population + history + concentration)`
```

Replica, value, concentration, population and history are all column headings in the dataframe.

Is there any way to format and export these so they are not unintelligible.
Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If the figure is unintelligible, then it's probably a sign that you are trying to display too much in the first place. Think about what is your motivation for the visualisation and evaluate if you do need to display all the plots in a single figure. If not, a sensible approach may be in displaying using a smaller data subset (less population type) for each figure, and generate out separate figures.

Answer (score 0):

As Adam points out... you're probably trying to show too much.

Having said that, a way to get it to work could be to use patchwork instead of facet_wrap.

```
dataframe$sets <- paste(dataframe$population, dataframe$history, dataframe$concentration)     
map(unique(dataframe$sets), ~ dataframe %>% filter(sets == .) %>% ggplot...)
patchwork::wrap_plots()
```

You'd probably want to add a geom_text or annotate or something with the "set". You'd still end up with small figures though and there's no real way around that without having a bigger figure (e.g. 20x10 instead of 10x5) or fewer individual plots (e.g. one figure for each population)